# Array of objects returns object Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, javascript-objects

I am trying to add an array of objects to my object, but when I look at it in console it looks like [object Object]

Code:

```
var myObj = new models.myObjModel({
     Name: req.body.Name,
     Id: req.body.Id,
     Balances: [ {type: req.body.Balances[0].type, balance: req.body.Balances[0].balance},
                 {type: req.body.Balances[1].type, balance: req.body.Balances[1].balance}
               ],
     Birthday: req.body.birthday,
     Gender: req.body.gender
  });
  console.log(this_Kiddy);
```

I get this:

```
{ Name: 'Ian',
  Id: '569496f45293a6170c3fe059',
  Birthday: Fri Dec 31 1999 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
  Gender: 'boy',
  _id: 56e8f2c0ef7b851539f481f0,
  Balances: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ] }
```

The Mongo insert looks like this:

```
Mongoose: person.insert({ __v: 0, Balances: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ], _id: ObjectId("56e8f2c0ef7b851539f481f0"), Gender: 'boy', Birthday: new Date("Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"), Id: '569496f45293a6170c3fe059', Name: 'Ian' }) {}
```

When I select balances, I get [object Object], not very useful. How can I actually get the balances?
Thanks in advanced.

EDIT:

here are previous log statements:

```
  console.log(req.body.Balances);
  console.log(req.body.Balances[0].type);
  console.log(req.body.Balances[0].balance);
  console.log(req.body.Balances[1].type);
  console.log(req.body.Balances[1].balance);
```

and output:

```
 [ { type: 'Balance1', balance: 2 },
   { type: 'Balance2', balance: 20 } ]
 Balance1
 2
 Balance2
 20
```

EDIT2:

```
var myObj = mongoose.Schema({  
  Name: { type: String },
  Id: { type: String },  
  Balances: [{
               type: String,
               balance: Number
            }],
  Birthday: {type: Date},
  Gender: {type: String}
});
```

Comment: This suggests that `req.body.Balances[0].type` *is* `'[object Object]'`. Please confirm that it is not (by logging it and showing us the output), or show us the code that generates it.

Comment: Can you print the result of `req.body.Balances[0]`?

Comment: I suspect more the code for the `models.myObjModel` class. Can you show that, please?

Comment: Looks like you are using alert function to see output; It shows only type like `[object Object]`

Comment: Your schema is wrong. Should be `Balances: [{ "type": { "type": String }, "balance": Number }]`. Mongoose thinks it's meant to be an array of strings unless you do that. So it's "stringifying" the array contents instead. Hence `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Yes, Type is a reserved word (duh). changed to mtype and I am good. Stupid mistake. Thanks Blakes